# How to hide these annoying gutters in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I scoured Google and SO for an answer but really couldn't find one, probably because I don't know the real name of these things.

[annoying gutter](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s139/sh/b1fee4ab-85c5-47cb-bd71-6666a57ee4cd/58a8696cd0a4994a2baefec8727d3ab7/res/315dfd08-bc20-43f1-bb17-223cc9ed3ef4/gutter-macvim-20120609-153858.png)

These gutters indicate nesting levels and folding options with little pluses and minuses and are completely useless to me, and take up a lot of spaces especially when working in split viewports.

Do you know how to get rid of them?

FYI I'm using the [Janus distribution](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)

Comment: This looks so good! How can I **enable** this?!

Comment: see below: `set foldcolumn=` but I really don't know why you would want that to be honest

Comment: On second though, I can see how annoying it can be. But at times, it would be nice to fold some functions. For example if you are adding a feature to your library, you would want to fold the previously written/tested functions out to keep your focus on the new ones.

Comment: you really don't need the columns to be folding in VIM! google `vim foldmethod` to learn more about it

Comment: Yeah I googled it as soon as I saw the answer below. And you are right, the sidebar is quite useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That "gutter" is the fold column. You can turn it off via

```
:set foldcolumn=0
```

However, this usually is set by a plugin or a filetype plugin, so it will probably reoccur. You can find out who did this via

```
:verbose set foldcolumn?
```

If it's been set up by a filetype plugin *foo*, you can put the command to turn it off into `.vim/after/ftplugin/foo.vim`. If it's a plugin, read up on its documentation. (That's the downside of pre-made Vim distributions like *Janus*!)

Comment: thanks I found it, it actually had to do with some old vimrc config that I didn't know was still active, and nothing to do with Janus ;)